# How to convert time period string in sleep format to seconds in bash

Tags: bash, parsing, time

This is about a time string in the format accepted by the common linux command [`sleep`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep),
like "3d 7h 5m 10s" (3 days, 7 hours, 5 minutes and 10 seconds),
which would have to result in:

`(3 * 24 * 60 * 60) + (7 * 60 * 60) + (5 * 60) + 10 = 284710` seconds

Note that not all these 4 elements must be present, nor in the right order,
and one element might appear multiple times.
So "3s 5s 6h" is valid too, and should result in:

`(6 * 60 * 60) + (3 + 5) = 21608` seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you replace the letters with the corresponding factors, you can pipe that to `bc`. You only need to take care of the `+` at the end of the line.

```
t2s() {
   sed 's/d/*24*3600 +/g; s/h/*3600 +/g; s/m/*60 +/g; s/s/\+/g; s/+[ ]*$//g' <<< "$1" | bc
}
```

Testrun

```
$ t2s "3d 7h 5m 10s"
284710
$ t2s "3d 7h 5m "
284700
$ t2s "3s 5s 6h"
21608
```

Answer (score 1):

A bash function based solution that supports days, hours, minutes and seconds.

file `sleepTimeToSeconds`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Converts a time string like "2h 3m 3s" to the amount of seconds
function timeToSeconds() {
    timeStr="$@"

    # validate
    grep -Pqx '( *\d+[smhd] +)+' <<< "$timeStr "
    if [ $? != 0 ]
    then
        >&2 echo "error: Bad time format"
        exit 1
    fi

    secs=0
    for timePart in $timeStr
    do
        timeType=${timePart//[[:digit:]]/}
        timeAmount=${timePart//[[:alpha:]]/}

        toSecsFactor=0
        case "$timeType" in
            s|'')
                toSecsFactor=1
                ;;
            m)
                toSecsFactor=60
                ;;
            h)
                let toSecsFactor="60 * 60"
                ;;
            d)
                let toSecsFactor="60 * 60 * 24"
                ;;
            *)
                >&2 echo "Bad time string type: '$timeType'"
                exit 2
                ;;
        esac
        let secs="$secs + ( $timeAmount * $toSecsFactor )"
    done

    echo -n $secs
}

timeToSeconds "$@"
```

test:

```
> sleepTimeToSeconds "5s 4s 1d 2h 3m"
93789
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a predefined command that fits your requirements, but I came up with a more compact and loop-free script using GNU `grep`, `paste`, and `bc`.

Usage examples, assuming the script is saved as `t2sec`:

- `t2sec 3s` prints `3`.
- `t2sec "2m 1s"`, `t2sec "1s 2m"`, `t2sec "1m 1s 1m"` all print `121`.
- `t2sec "1s 2s"`, `t2sec "1s2s"`, `t2sec 1s 2s`, `t2sec "  1s 2s "` all print `3`.
- `t2sec`, `t2sec ""`, `t2sec "1x"`, `t2sec "s"` all print nothing and exit with status of 1.

```
#! /bin/bash  

t="$*"

# validate
grep -Pqx '( *\d+[smhd])+ *' <<< "$t" || exit 1

# helper functions
sumAndMultiply() { bc <<< "(0$(paste -s -d+))*$1"; }
xToSeconds() { grep -Po "\\d+(?=$1)" | sumAndMultiply "$2"; }

# convert to seconds
(
        xToSeconds s 1 <<< "$t";
        xToSeconds m 60 <<< "$t";
        xToSeconds h 3600 <<< "$t";
        xToSeconds d 86400 <<< "$t";
) | sumAndMultiply 1
```

Comment: thanks! nice solution, just like @Walter A's. don't know which of the two to pick...
also stole your validation for my solution, with a tiny change ensuring spaces between time parts: `grep -Pqx '( *\d+[smhd] )+ *' <<< "$t " || exit 1` (just added two spaces, one in the regex and one after the variable)

Comment: @hoijui Thanks for your reply. I would go with walter's solution + validation. His solution is very clever, more efficient and easier to maintain than my solution. PS: To ensure spaces, you can also write `' +'` instead of  `' * '`.

Answer (score 1):

In the rare case you don't have `bc` available:
(perhaps bash-on-Windows like I suffer with?)

Then the @WalterA function `t2s` can be changed to this:

```
t2s() {
   eq=$(sed 's/d/*24*3600 +/g; s/h/*3600 +/g; s/m/*60 +/g; s/s/\+/g; s/+[ ]*$//g' <<< "$1")
   ((val=eq))
   echo "$val"
}
```

Comment: Also works on one line for me: `t2s() { echo $(($(sed 's/d/*24*3600 +/g; s/h/*3600 +/g; s/m/*60 +/g; s/s/\+/g; s/+[ ]*$//g' <<< "$@"))); }`